# How to move DropdownMenu to preferable location in Jepack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, compose-desktop

Is it possible to center `DropdownMenu` in my example? or show it wherever I click or tap?

I tried alignment and arrangements and none of them work. I prefer showing the `DropdownMenu`  wherever I tab but I couldn't find a way to do it.

[image: Desktop Compose]

```
fun main() = Window {
    var helloText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Item("Darian", "Russ") {
            helloText = it
        }
        Item("Maynerd", "Andre") {
            helloText = it
        }
        Item("Sandra", "Victoria") {
            helloText = it
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        Text(text = helloText)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Item(text: String, text2: String, onMenuTab: (String) -> Unit) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        val modifier = Modifier.clickable {
            expanded = true
        }
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                expanded = false
            }
        ) {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                onMenuTab("hello $text $text2")
                expanded = false
            }, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)) {
                Text("Hello")
            }
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { /* Handle settings! */ }) {
                Text("Settings")
            }
            Divider()
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { /* Handle send feedback! */ }) {
                Text("Send Feedback")
            }
        }
        Text(text = text, modifier = modifier)
        Text(text = text2, modifier = modifier)
        Divider(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
    }
}
```

Comment: I did add some detail but It wasn't enough.

Comment: Please answer the question it you can. @PhilipDukhov

Comment: It kinda worked for my test desktop compose but it is working for my actual android app. I don't know why.

Comment: It works. Is it possible to show it where ever I touch or click on a Composable?

Comment: No, `DropdownMenu` was made specifically to display below the interacting element. You have to create it yourself. You can take it source code as reference. If that answer helped you, please upvote it=)

Comment: I want the question to stay open to see potential answers.

Comment: Sure I see that it's not really a duplicate.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov The code snippet showed in the link does NOT center the dropdown menu. As far as I'm concerned, the OP's question is still unanswered.

Comment: @kc_dev that's why my last comment in this discussion says "I see that it's not really a duplicate.". But I've removed my comment with the linked question too now.

Answer (score 0):

For me fixing the alignment of the popup did the trick-

`Popup(alignment = Alignment.TopStart)`

Earlier it was `Popup(alignment = Alignment.CenterStart)`

and that was taking my popup view to the top of the screen. But now comes below the clicked item.